# Using sql where clause

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to implement the following query

```
$sql20 = "SELECT * FROM API_paw where Valid>0 AND KeyType=API"; 
$rs20 = CustomQuery($sql20);
```

I can do this with one where variable, but this is first time I have used two and my syntax is not correct, I know its a basic question but would appreciate someone saving me time.

Comment: You just need some spaces and quotes - `SELECT * FROM API_paw where Valid > 0 AND KeyType = 'API'` Are you getting an actual error? What is it?

Comment: Add a tag for your specific DBMS, depending of what you are using you can get a syntax error or not

Comment: You need to quote strings. IE `... AND KeyType = 'API'`.

Answer (score 0):

@JayBlanchard and @ʰᵈ are right; you need to quote your strings. Also, if you copy the query and execute it in your DBMS it'll probably be very clear what the error is.